# JetBrains Toolbox won't start on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I tried installing JB Toolbox on Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded it from the official website and extracted it to opt using this

```
sudo tar -xzf jetbrains-toolbox-1.21.9712.tar.gz -C /opt
```

But when I open it using .`/jetbrains-toolbox` command it opens up in the background and closes within around 10 seconds (checked this using the `top` command). Nothing can be seen in the UI. Not even the top bar icon can be seen.

I checked the logs `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/logs` in this location but nothing can be found as well.

I tried this on wayland and x11 but still not working.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you give it the proper permissions?

Answer (score 10):

For me it was an issue with missing `libfuse`.

```
0728 Apr  4  2022 /opt/jetbrains-toolbox-1.23.11731/jetbrains-toolbox
sandeep@maystreet-work-pc:~$ /opt/jetbrains-toolbox-1.23.11731/jetbrains-toolbox 
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run. 
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
```

I was able to fix it by installing `libfuse2`:

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

In any case, running `jetbrains-toolbox` from command line will help and it is located in `/opt`. For me the complete path is `/opt/jetbrains-toolbox-1.23.11731/jetbrains-toolbox`

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr: Adjust file permissions and invoke using `sudo`

Just going on what you have written so far, you also need to give the app the execute permission.

one way to do this is to use the `chmod` command as follows:

```bsh
sudo chmod u+x /opt/rest-of-the-qualified-pathname
```

The relative path will work as well, in case you already have a terminal opened to the parent directory.

The instructions above assume that you are the owner of the file. If
you have doubts about ownership, here are some other options that you can use. It is up to you to decide which best fits your situation.

In the `u+x` bit above, the `u` is for user, and so it will be runnable only by you (assuming no other permissions are set.) The options here are 'u' for user(owner of the file, not the user running the command, which should be root anyway), 'g' for group (which denotes the owner's home group), 'o' for other (to change the permission for users not in the owner's group), or 'a' for all. Additionally, leaving that character out completely, as in

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /opt/rest-of-the-qualified-pathname
```

will work as well for most at-home single user Ubuntu desktop installations.

##### EDIT:

Once the program is installed, it will usually need to be invoked with escalated privileges. The best way to do this is with the following command:

```bsh
sudo ./jetbrains-toolbox
```

As it stands, this needs to be called from inside `/opt`. If you want to call from another directory, change the invocation to:

```bsh
sudo /opt/jetbrains-toolbox
```

Below are a couple of options that will let you omit the full-path invocation.

**OPTION 1**

If you add `/opt` to $PATH, then you will be able to call the program name as a command. The command to add it to $PATH is:

```bsh
echo 'export PATH="${PATH}:/opt"' | sudo tee -a ~/etc/environment.d/99-addoptdir.conf
source /etc/environment.d/99-addoptdir.conf
```

The first line adds a command to add it to $PATH, and it adds it in a way that ensures that it is run each time a shell instance is created (more or less each time you open up a terminal.) Since the current shell was created *before* the command was added, trying to type the command in this shell won't work. Therefore, the second line is a workaround that runs the `99-addoptdir.conf` retroactively.

Now the following command should work:

```
sudo jetbrains-toolbox
```

Remember that it will not work in any terminals that were already opened. If you need it to do so, run the source command above in each old terminal that you need it to work in.

**OPTION 2**

You can also use this command to set a "shortcut command" which will
get it working quickly.

```
# Use this if ~/.bash_aliases exists in your file system
echo 'alias jbtb="sudo /opt/jetbrains-toolbox"' | sudo tee -a ~/.bash_aliases

# Otherwise use this one
echo 'alias jbtb="sudo /opt/jetbrains-toolbox"' | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can open the program with the command:

```
jbtb
```

No need for typing out paths or even sudo. Although you will need to type in your password. Working around that part is never a good idea. XD

This method uses an alias, and some people have mixed feelings about aliases, because they feel that they are a hindrance to new users learning the "real" commands. However, it works, and at the end of the day, that is usually what matters most.

**IMPORTANT!  Make sure that the `-a` flag is included after the `tee` command, anywhere it is used above! If it is left out, your entire .bashrc file will be overwritten! If you'd like, you can just copy / paste the command(s) to be safe. **

Comment: How is this applicable? Wouldn't the terminal complain about permissions, instead of "running" for ten seconds and then returning with exit code 0?

Comment: When it gets started without the proper permissions, the error message (or lack thereof) is usually the responsibility of the program's developer. The OS will send a signal which is supposed to be caught by the program and trigger the error msg, logging actions, etc. That is why the error msg displayed Is worded differently for each program. I probably gave the answer above because the OP put the executable in `/opt/`.

Comment: The `/opt` directory is not on `$PATH` by default, so every program placed here has to have its permissions set (first octal must be 1,3, or 7) or else it wont run... or you cn just add `/opt` to $PATH. That would be the same as setting exec perms for everything inside.

Comment: @EtienneBruines How is this? This (after edit) was the solution that the OP needed. I would bet the farm on it. Didnt realize Id left out `sudo` invocation. Thx for pointing it out.

Comment: I learned something new - always thought it would always result in an error, regardless of what the application was/did. I always got `zsh: permission denied: ` when trying to run non-executable files. (Even when it is part of the `PATH`)

Comment: @EtienneBruines You are 100% correct, permissions would prevent the application from running at all if an application would just be 'sent a signal which is supposed to be caught by the program' this would be a massive security breach. I don't think what Nate is saying is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please  make sure that these libraries are installed :
`libfuse2 libxi6 libxrender1 libxtst6 mesa-utils libfontconfig libgtk-3-bin tar`